# Extract URLs from inside img html tag across multiple files

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a folder with lots of .html files, the files have `<p>..</p>` html tags and `<img...>` html tags across all of them

I am trying to extract **ONLY the URLs** **found inside the `<img...>` html** tags across all files in the current folder into one single `output.txt` file

The html files code looks like this:

```
file1.html
<p> text...</p>
<img style='display' src="https://www.example.com/image1.jpg" width="100px" alt="image1"/>
<p> text...</p>
<p> text.. <a href="https://www.example.com/1">1</a> ... text....</p>
```

```
file2.html
<p> text...</p>
<img style='display' src="https://www.example.com/image2.jpg" width="100px" alt="image2"/>
<p> text...</p>
<p> text.. <a href="https://www.example.com/2">2</a> ... text....</p>
```

There's no specific pattern with images URLs paths, they can have anything in the URL path.

My problem is some of these html files might have other URLs besides inside the  html tag, so I need to extract only from the `<img ...>` html tag.

Ideally, I am trying to extract all the URLs found inside the `<img ...>` html tags into an output.txt which would look like this:

```
output.txt
https://www.example.com/image1.jpg
https://www.example.com/image2.jpg
etc
```

**Would this be possible with sed or Regex somehow?**

I tried using this sed command but it seems it extracted all the URLs no matter where they were found:

```
sed -n 's#.*\(https*://[^"]*\).*#\1#;p' file
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **really** don't want to use `sed` or `grep` or any regexp-only based extraction method.  HTML is structured text, so you need a HTML parser to reliably extract data from it.

There are HTML parsing libraries available for most languages, including C, go, rust, java, python, php, perl, and many more.   There are also command-line tools like `xml_grep` and `xmlstarlet` for parsing and processing HTML/XHTML/XML files in a shell script - they're good, but in my experience they tend to be far more strict about requiring the input file to conform to specifications.  For HTML in particular, this can cause problems - strict adherence to specs isn't exactly common for real-world websites (which is a polite way of saying "HTML files are often garbage").  Parsing libs tend to be a lot more forgiving about what they will process, readily handling input that would be rejected by stricter tools.

BTW, there are also tools like `xml2` and `html2` for converting structured text into a line oriented format that can more easily be processed with line-oriented tools like grep, sed, cut, etc.

Anyway, using a HTML parser is not only more reliable than using a regular expression, it's generally much easier too.

Here's an example using Perl's [HTML::TokeParser::Simple](https://metacpan.org/release/HTML-TokeParser-Simple) parser, a simple interface to the [HTML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/release/HTML-Parser) module.  If you're running any common Linux distro, these will almost certainly be available as packages - e.g. on Debian and derivatives, they are packaged as `libhtml-tokeparser-simple-perl` and `libhtml-parser-perl`.  Otherwise, it can be installed with `cpan`.

```perl
$ cat extract-img-urls.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use v5.16;   # for fc (fold case) function

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

foreach my $f (@ARGV) {
  my $p = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(file => $f);
  while (my $token = $p->get_token) {
    next unless fc($token->[1]) eq fc('img');
    print $token->[2]->{src} . "\n";
  }
};
```

Save this to a file, and make it executable with chmod - e.g. `chmod +x ./extract-img-urls.pl`

Run it with the list of HTML files you want it to process as the arguments.  You can do that manually, or use something like `find` and `-exec` to feed it that list of filenames - e.g. this shows I only have two IMG SRC URLs in my `index.html`, both of them relative:

```
$ find ~/public_html/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'index.html' -exec ./extract-img-urls.pl {} +
cas.jpg
valid-html401.png
```

Obviously, using `find` to match a single file in a single directory is overkill.  This would work just as well as `./extract-img-urls.pl ~/public_html/index.html`....but that wouldn't be a good example for multiple files in multiple subdirectories.

In your case, you probably want to run it with `-name '*.html'` (or `-iname '*.html'` for a case-insensitive match).   And you may want to remove the `-maxdepth 1` predicate too, so that it will also find .html files in subdirectories.

```
find ~/public_html/ -type f -iname '*.html' -exec ./extract-img-urls.pl {} +
```

Finally, this example assumes that the perl script is in the current directory.  If not, specify the actual path to it instead of `./`...or if you put it somewhere in your $PATH (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/`, and it's fairly common practice to make a `~/bin/` directory and add it to their $PATH for their own scripts) you can run it from anywhere without needing to specify the path, same as you do with common programs like find, grep, sed, awk, perl, etc.

---

IMG SRC urls are often relative URLs.  To (very simplistically) add the base directory for each relative image filename, using the `dirname()` function from the [File::Basename](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Basename) module (a core perl module included with perl):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use v5.16;   # for fc (fold case) function

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;
use File::Basename;

foreach my $f (@ARGV) {
  my $base = dirname($f);
  my $p = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(file => $f);
  while (my $token = $p->get_token) {
    next unless fc($token->[1]) eq fc('img');
    if ($token->[2]->{src} =~ m=^(https?|ftp)://|^/=i) {
      print $token->[2]->{src} . "\n";
    } else {
      print $base . "/" . $token->[2]->{src} . "\n";
    }
  }
};
```

Output:

```
$ find ~/public_html/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'index.html' -exec ./extract-img-urls.pl {} +
/home/cas/public_html/cas.jpg
/home/cas/public_html/valid-html401.png
```

---

Finally, here's a version that prints the name of each file it processes, inserts a tab before each IMG SRC url, and a newline (`\n`) after each file.  The newline separator is useful if you want to process the output with other tools or scripts.  It's easy to process such text as many tools/languages have options to read data in "paragraph mode".

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use v5.16;   # for fc (fold case) function

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;
use File::Basename;

foreach my $f (@ARGV) {
  print "$f\n";
  my $base = dirname($f);
  my $p = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(file => $f);
  while (my $token = $p->get_token) {
    next unless fc($token->[1]) eq fc('img');
    if ($token->[2]->{src} =~ m=^(https?|ftp)://|^/=i) {
      print "\t" . $token->[2]->{src} . "\n";
    } else {
      print "\t" . $base . "/" . $token->[2]->{src} . "\n";
    }
  };
  print "\n";
};
```

In the sample output below, the first line of each paragraph is the filename, and the remaining lines are the IMG SRC URLs prefixed by a tab (the tab is mostly for human readability, but is also useful if any filenames contain newlines...this is not perfect, as it will still have a problem if a filename contains a newline followed by a tab. That's why it is often recommended to use a NUL character as a filename separator, it's the ONLY character that isn't valid in a path/filename)

```
$ ./extract-img-urls2.pl ~/public_html/index*.html
/home/cas/public_html/index.html
        /home/cas/public_html/cas.jpg
        /home/cas/public_html/valid-html401.png

/home/cas/public_html/index.old.html
        /home/cas/public_html/cas.jpg
```

---

##### perl programming, variable references, arrays, objects, etc

tl;dr: it's magic.

BTW, you may be wondering why the scripts use variables like `$token->[1]` and `$token->[2]->{src}`.  That's because I examined the structure of the object returned by the `get_token` method, which is a `HTML::TokeParser::Simple::Token::Tag::Start` object with a data structure that looks like this:

```
[
  'S',
  'img',
   { 'src' => 'valid-html401.png',
     'width' => '88',
     'alt' => 'Valid HTML 4.01 Transitional',
     'height' => '31'
   },
   [ 'src',     
     'alt',       
     'height',
     'width'      
   ],
   '<img src="valid-html401.png" alt="Valid HTML 4.01 Transitional" height="31" width="88">'
]
```

This is an indexed array that contains a string `'S'` (which means the current token is a start tag like `<p>`..."E" would mean an end tag like `</p>`) as element 0, a string containing the HTML tag name `'img'` as element 1, a hash (associative array, in `{...}`) containing the HTML tag's attribute names (keys) and values as element 2, another indexed array or "list" containing the attribute names again as element 4 (in `[...]`), and the actual html text for the img src tag as element 5.

This is documented in `man HTML::TokeParser`, which says that an "S" type token has `["S",  $tag, $attr, $attrseq, $text]`.  The `Argspec` section of `man HTML::Parser` explains why it contains a hash ($attr) AND an array containing the keys of the hash ($attrseq). It's because hashes are inherently unordered and the array is being used to remember the original order that the keys were seen in the `img` tag in the HTML source.  That's a pretty common technique for getting the convenience of a hash without losing the order of the keys.

In the perl code, `$token->[1]` refers to the 2nd element (perl arrays start from 0, not 1), so we check to see if it is `img` (case-insensitive).  If it is, then we print the `src` key of the hash in `$token->[2]`: `$token->[2]->{src}`.

The `->` is called the "arrow operator" and is used to de-reference (access) values within a data structure, very similar to how it's used in C or C++.

You can find out more about perl data by reading the man pages for `perldata`, `perllol` (lol="lists-of-lists", AKA arrays-of-arrays, which are arrays that contain other arrays) and `perldsc` (the "Perl Data Structures Cookbook").  See also `man perlref` and the tutorial `man perlreftut`.

The arrow operator is also used to call methods (i.e. subroutines) in perl object-oriented programming (see `man perlobj`)...you can see examples of this in the code above with `$p = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(...)` to create `$p` as a new `HTML::TokeParser::Simple` object, and `$p->get_token` to call `$p`'s `get_token()` method (and store the object it returns in variable `$token`).

You can use modules like [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/release/Data-Dump) or [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) to pretty-print data structures and objects while you're developing/debugging code like this....which is often faster & less work than trawling through the documentation.

`Data:Dumper` is a core module, included with perl.  `Data::Dump` isn't but is easily installed on Debian etc with `apt-get install libdata-dump-perl` or with `cpan`.  They're both good, but I generally prefer the output style of `Data::Dump`.

BTW, you can't do complex data structures like this in `bash` - bash supports arrays and associative arrays (AKA "hashes"), but elements can only contain simple scalar values like individual strings or numbers.   They can not contain nested arrays or hashes.  Bash (and some other bourne-like shells) has some variable referencing capabilities, but if you find yourself using them, you really should be using a better language (which is almost any other language) - bash is not a good language for data processing, it's a language for setting up and coordinating the execution of other programs (grep, sed, cut, perl, awk, and many more).

Comment: wow thanks a lot @cas, I will try it and reply back with an update, thank you!

Comment: hey @ cas I created the local `extract-img-urls.pl` file in my folder, and from my understanding this is applicable for 1 file at a time right? so i need to run it for each html file i have ?

When i did run the command in the terminal in the current folder, i am getting this error in the terminal `find: ‘./extract-img-urls.pl’: Permission denied`

Comment: 1. No, the script can accept any number of filename arguments on the command line. That's why I showed the example using `find` (in your case, use `-name '*.html'` instead of the `-name 'index.html'` I used.  and remove the `-maxdepth 1` if you want it to recurse sub-directories too). The `{}` in the find command line is replaced by **all** matchings files (and if there are more than will fit on one command line, find will just run the script two or more times as required).   2. You need to make the script executable with chmod before you can run it.  e.g. `chmod +x ./extract-img-urls.pl`.

Comment: BTW, the `foreach my $f (@ARGV) { ... }` loop iterates over each filename on the command line.  It's similar to you would iterate over all filename arguments in bash with something like `for f in "$@"; do ... ; done`.  In bash script, `"$@"` is an array containing all arguments to the script, and in perl, `@ARGV` is an array containing all args to the perl script.

Comment: @ cas thanks a lot for the explanations! i was able to run the Perl script in the end on 1,000 files and it worked beautifully; I can confirm it found all img URLs.

I ran this command and put my current folder path `find CURRENT-FOLDER-PATH -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.html' -exec ./extract-img-urls.pl {} +`

would it be possible to output all these img URLs to an `output.txt` file instead of the command line? thank you!

Comment: It would be easy to modify the perl script to open an output file and print directly to that (hint: start by reading `perldoc -f open`), but it's easier and more flexible to just print to stdout and use redirection in the shell. e.g. `find ... -exec ... > output.txt`. You can also pipe it to another program (or to a series of programs in a pipeline) before redirecting to a file or viewing the output on the terminal or in a program like `less`. This is pretty fundamental to "the unix way" - write your own custom small tools and combine them with other, standard tools.

Comment: @ cas worked like a charm, it saved the info to the `output.txt` file. By the way instead of running the command where I gave it an exact path to the folder `find CURRENT-FOLDER-PATH -maxdepth ...` , is there a way to run the command in the current folder (I run it locally) and not need to add in full path to the current folder? I know I can run for instance `pwd` and get current folder path, but was wondering how can i use the `find ..` command and not need to add the folder path manually all the time

Comment: just use `.` or `"$PWD"` (which is automatically set & updated by your shell. It's a variable so remember to double-quote it when you use it) to refer to the current directory. find will also default to the current dir if you don't specify a directory.  Or use your own variable, e.g. `find "$mydir" ....`.   BTW, you can give find multiple directories before the first predicate and it will search them all - `find . dir1 ../dir2 "$mydir" -maxdepth 1 ....`

Comment: thx a bunch @ cas ! worked like a charm with `.`  : ) this has been saving me so much time, i greatly appreciate the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -n '/<img/s/.*src=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' file1 file2
https://www.example.com/image1.jpg
https://www.example.com/image2.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with an XML parser.

```
for file in *.html
do
    xmlstarlet format --html "$file" 2>/dev/null |
        xmlstarlet select --template --value-of '//img/@src' --nl
done >output.txt
```

What this does is force HTML into well formed XML, and then select the `src` attribute value from each `<img/>` tag in turn. The entire result set is written to `output.txt`

If your HTML files are already well formed XML you can dispense with the explicit loop and simplify the entire sequence to a single command

```
xmlstarlet select --template --value-of '//img/@src' --nl *.html >output.txt
```

or less verbosely

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//img/@src' -n *.html >output.txt
```

Comment: thanks @ roaima ! I tried to run the command in the terminal but getting this error on all files `Extra content at the end of the document` ; i believe this is because my html files are not formatted properly : | ; i'll test it again on other files

Comment: I've tested on XML files but still getting an error `Extra content at the end of the document` which from my understanding it is due to wrong format of the files

Comment: You're using the short version instead of the loop. That's a typical error when parsing data that doesn't have a single top level element. The extra`xmlstarlet format --html` will (attempt to) fix that

Comment: @ roaima i tried running this command on my Linux Mint `for file in *.html
do
    xmlstarlet format --html "$file" 2>/dev/null |
        xmlstarlet select --template --value-of '//img/@src' --nl
done >output.txt` but getting this error showing up continuously (like a loop) `-:1.1: Document is empty` . From what i read, it might be because of Ubuntu but not 100% sure :|

Comment: You do have files matching `*.html` in your current directory, don't you? I'm only going from what you described in your question, but your error message would indicate that you don't

Comment: I think i had wrong formatting of the html inside the files; yes you are right, my mistake, I was running the command in a folder that did not have html files anymoore, my bad

Answer (score 0):

This will most likely do what you want, assuming the img tags are never broken up on multiple lines:

```
grep -oh '<img[^>]*>' *.html | sed 's/.*\ssrc=['"'"'"]//' | sed 's/['"'"'"].*//' > output.txt
```

There may be an easier way. Not sure.

Comment: thanks @frabjous for this, seems it worked but gonna try as well the Perl script mentioned below

Comment: I tested it on about 10 files and seemed it worked fine, I'll test on more files and let you know, thx!

Comment: @ frabjous confirming I have tested this on 1,000 files and it extracted all img URLs correctly

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
grep '^<img' *.html | grep -o 'http[^"]*' > output.txt
```

Comment: thanks @fuzzy drawings , this worked too but i am also gonna try as well the Perl script mentioned by cas below

Comment: I ran this command on about 10 files and worked fine, I will test it on a larger sample of files and let you know how it goes

Comment: @ fuzzy drawings I tested this on 1,000 files and it worked fine, it extract the img URLs

Answer (score 0):

With `pcregrep`, you can get it to `o`utput the contents of the `1`<sup>st</sup> capture group case `i`nsensitively and in a `M`ulti-line fashion with:

```
pcregrep -iMo1 '<img[^>]*src="(http[^>"]*)"'
```

With GNU `grep` or compatible, built with PCRE support, you can achieve something similar with:

```
grep -Poz '<img[^>]*src="\Khttp[^>"]*(?=")' | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Comment: thanks @ Stéphane Chazelas , I ran the command in the terminal (I am on Linux Mint) and it's all blank, does not seem to process the files. Is there another argument that I am missing? i mean to apply to all the files in the current folder?